# EF Core: Relationships and tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have this kind of simplified tructure

```
class User
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    List<UserItem> Items;
}

class Item
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}

class UserItem
{
    int Id;
    int UserId;
    int ItemId;
    int Value;

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    User User;

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")] 
    Item Item;
}
```

Now lets add new item for user

```
User user = context.Users.Include(u => u.Items).ThenInclude(i => i.Item).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);

Item item = context.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 123);

UserItem userItem = new UserItem();
userItem.UserId = user.Id;
userItem.User = user;
userItem.ItemId = item.Id;
userItem.Item = item;
userItem.Value = 123;

context.Add(userItem);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Exception happens because EF tries to INSERT the item if I set the foreign key values manually. If I only set ids, then no issues. However I need the foreign key values present because they are needed in somewhere else in code.

I can't use `AsNoTracking()` when querying the user because I want to track the User and its UserItems (but not the Item).

I have solved this with `context.Entity(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged` which seems kind of hacky.

Comment: You should be fine with just setting `User` and `Item` properties. Id's will be updated after `SaveChanges`

Comment: Have you tried adding the item to `User.Items` instead of trying to set the IDs yourself? Something like `user.Items.Add(new UserItem{Item=item})`

Comment: I see. Bunch of my code uses `UserId` or `ItemId` between `Add()` and `SaveChanges()` because sometimes I have not included the foreign property for performance reasons, since it is not needed for many requests.